# What is the right way to post image to REST API and gather data with Falcon library?

Tags: api, rest, post, upload, falconframework

I try to post an image to process it through my REST API. I use falcon for the backend but could not figure out how to post and receive the data.

This is how I currently send my file

```
img = open('img.png', 'rb')
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/rec",
files={'file':img},
data = {'apikey' : 'bla'})
```

However at the Falcon repo they say that Falcon does not support HTML forms to send data instead it aims full scope of POSTed and PUTed data which I do not differentiate POSTed image data and the one sent as above.

So eventually, I like to learn what is the right workaround to send a image and receive it by a REST API which is supposedly written by Falcon. Could you give some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use the following approach:

Falcon API Code:

```
import falcon
import base64
import json

app = falcon.API()
app.add_route("/rec/", GetImage())

class GetImage:

    def on_post(self, req, res):

        json_data = json.loads(req.stream.read().decode('utf8'))
        image_url = json_data['image_name']
        base64encoded_image = json_data['image_data']
        with open(image_url, "wb") as fh:
            fh.write(base64.b64decode(base64encoded_image))

        res.status = falcon.HTTP_203
        res.body = json.dumps({'status': 1, 'message': 'success'})
```

For API call:

```
import requests
import base64

with open("yourfile.png", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_image = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/rec/", 
                  data={'image_name':'yourfile.png',
                        'image_data':encoded_image
                       }
                 )
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: I blv if you are using json.loads to recv the data, then json.dumps must be used to send it

Comment: if you send 'data' then JSON won't work, u need to send JSON not data